# Is there anything wrong with keeping oil, salt, and vinegar together?

Tags: oil, salt, food-preservation, vinegar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Need to refrigerate vinaigrette?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/13803/need-to-refrigerate-vinaigrette)

I am curious if there is anything wrong with keeping oil, salt, and vinegar together.

A month ago, I made a small mixture of those and brought it to my work, to use it for salad. Do some of them cause some unwanted chemical interactions? I use rapeseed oil, sea salt, and ordinary vinegar. I didn't refrigerate them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, as you can keep them separately for a long time, The point is, no chemical reaction accur because they don't have right particles for a chemical reaction, it's just a mixture and no new substances is made. I think they are still healthy like that.

Also, accroding to a very nice article about keeping oil and vinager ( http://oilandvinegar.cruets.com/keeping-oil-and-vinegar ), despite they can be stored for a long period of time , depends on the place and container you keep them in:

> Olive oil and vinegar have four deadly enemies. They are:
>   1. Age
>   2. Heat
>   3. Light
>   4. Air
>
> One of the above or a combination of any of these four can damage
>   olive oil and vinegar beyond measure.

So in a dark and cool place and not a plastic container,they can be stored for 15 months.

Comment: Even if the conclusion might be OK, your first sentence is very dangerous - if you can keep two foods for long time unrefrigerated, it doesn't mean that their mixture will keep! (Consider sugar and water, their mixture doesn't undergo a chemical reaction but it is ideal for bacteria). Thus the downvote, even if this special case of oil + vinegar could turn out to be unproblematic.

Comment: But I smelled it after a month and it smells like shampoo, so I'll bring myself new ;)

Comment: @rumtscho We're talking about this special case and I'm pretty sure it's healthy.

Comment: @Explorer: "Pretty sure" is a dangerous term in regards to food safety...